# How are name clashes avoided for IPFS DNSLINK?

Tags: ipfs

https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/concepts/dnslink/

I think ipns uses a hash of your public peer id or something to create unique namespaces. I see no comment about how this works for DNSLink. What are the subspaces for DNSLink? If there is a global namespace as the documents suggest, how is this handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you ask how we handle DNSLink and IPNS  on the same namespace when resolving `/ipns/{value}`.

In go-ipfs 0.4.23 we check if `value` is a valid Peer ID (see [spec](https://github.com/libp2p/specs/blob/master/peer-ids/peer-ids.md#peer-ids)), if not, check if `value` is a [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) with a [DNSLink](https://dnslink.dev/) record.

Comment: I think I'm asking something simpler ... the docs make it sound like anyone can grab /ipns/something via DNSLink. Is there scoping for FQDN? You can name squat?

Comment: You can't set DNSLink if you are not the owner of FQDN. DNSLink itself is limited by the DNS spec. 

You can use any FQDN you want, as long it has a DNS TXT record with DNSLink that can be resolved by a DNS resolver present in user's operating system.